# What does backticks do when in beginning of line in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, syntax

I have noticed a weird behavior when a backtick is used in the beginning of line in bash scripts.

- example 1:

  ```bash
  echo "Test"
  `ls`
  ```

  Output:

  ```
  Test
  ```

  and `ls` is ignored.
- example 2:

  ```bash
  `test ':";`|)%$kasdj`
  ```

  This should return an error but it doesn't , it acts like a comment.

Comment: Get access to the HTML version of POSIX, or your local manual pages my friend! See my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

The

```
`ls`
```

in your first script fragment substitutes the command with the output of `ls` and executes it. If it's an empty directory, then nothing is substituted and nothing happens.

In your second example, the number of backticks is odd not even. So there's a syntax error.

Comment: More precisely, in sh / bash,  `\`ls\`` runs the command whose arguments (and the command name is derived from the first) is the result of split+glob applied to the output of `ls` stripped of its trailing newline characters. For instance, if `ls` outputs `* *<newline>` because there's a file named `* *` in the current directory and `$IFS` is the default, `* *` would be split into `*` and `*` and each `*` expanded to the non-hidden files in the current directory, so would try to run the equivalent of `'* *' '* *'`